# mixing two audio track using mlt

Tags: audio

Am using mlt framework for editing audio and video track. Now I have a use case like, have a audio track where one person is singing song without music and have another track where I have music for the song. Now I want to mix this, I mean with the song I want to add the music track. Please suggest me which melt command should I use?

Thanks
Sougata

Answer (score 1):

if You have two audio clip in mp3 or other format try this:

melt avformat:a.mp3 out=400 -move in=0 out=400 -track avformat:b.mp3 out=400 -transition mix in=0 out=400 a_track=0 b_track=1